# My Android studio run menu is deactivated

Tags: android, plugins

My android studio gives me a plugin error and loads project but the run button is deactivated. Below is the even log

```
8/5/2017
2:46 PM Platform and Plugin Updates: Android Studio is ready to update.

2:46 PM AbstractMethodError: null

2:46 PM AbstractMethodError: null

2:46 PM Plugin Error
                Problems found loading plugins:
                Plugin "Android Games" was not loaded: required plugin "Android Support" is disabled.
                Plugin "Android NDK Support" was not loaded: required plugin "Android Support" is disabled.
                Plugin "NDK WorkspaceManager Support" was not loaded: required plugin "Android Support" is disabled.
                Plugin "Firebase App Indexing" was not loaded: required plugin "Android Support" is disabled.
                Plugin "Google Developers Samples" was not loaded: required plugin "Android Support" is disabled.
                Plugin "Google Cloud Tools For Android Studio" was not loaded: required plugin "Android Support" is disabled.
                Plugin "Test Recorder" was not loaded: required plugin "Android Support" is disabled.
                Plugin "Firebase Testing" was not loaded: required plugin "Android Support" is disabled.
                Plugin "Google Services" was not loaded: required plugin "Android Support" is disabled.
                Plugin "Firebase Services" was not loaded: required plugin "Android Support" is disabled.
                P... (show balloon)

2:47 PM Plugins Suggestion
                Unknown feature (Run Configuration[AndroidRunConfigurationType]) covered by disabled plugin detected.
                Enable plugins...
                Ignore Unknown Features
```

Comment: go to configure> plugins , is there any red dots ?

Answer (score 0):

This due to missing Plugins.Enable Android Studio Plugin to resolve the issue